# Comparing two Dates using strtotime() in PHP

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I have two variables containing strings of dates in the format

```
$four_days_have_passed = "07-14-2013";
$now = "07-10-2013";
```

I have checked the output in FirePHP and the dates are correct.

Then I try to compare them like this,

```
if (strtotime($now) < strtotime($four_days_have_passed))
{
  Do Stuff
}
```

Why does the code inside the IF statement never execute?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use MM/DD/YYYY format you need `/` separator.

```
$four_days_have_passed = "07/14/2013";
$now = "07/10/2013";
```

**[From the manual](http://www.php.net/strtotime):-**

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed.

Comment: he doesn't need `/` he needs proper format. He can use `14-07-2013` too :)

Answer (score 3):

I see you accepted answer but just to make sure you understand. There are 2 cases that dates are parsed.

1. American - month/day/year
2. European - day.month.year or day-month-year

You have error because you provided european format  `"07-14-2013"` and there's no 14 month in year.

The proper format for you is one of these:

- `14-07-2013` - Europe
- `14.07.2013` - Europe
- `07/14/2013` - American

Morover, to compare datatime it's better to use object oriented solution and DataTime object. You can read more [here.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Answer (score 2):

The format (when used like that) is DD-MM-YYYY. There is no 14th month.

Comment: I have forced the format to `$now = date('m-d-Y', strtotime($getCurrentDate . "+0 day")); $four_days_have_passed = date('m-d-Y', strtotime($getRepDate . "+4 days"));`

Comment: @David Folksman: no you haven't. `strtotime` doesn't expect it to be in american format.

Comment: Hence why I used the format m-d-y, i dont understand your answer?

Comment: @David Folksman: `strtotime` accepts the date to be in either `YYYY-MM-DD` (preferred) or `DD-MM-YYYY` format. That's it. More accepted formats here: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php

Comment: Works here? http://writecodeonline.com/php/ `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
 
 $getCurrentDate = str_replace('/', '-',$_REQUEST['date']);
    $four_days_have_passed = date('m-d-Y', strtotime($getCurrentDate . "+4 days"));
 
 $now = date('m-d-Y', strtotime($rep1 . "+0 day"));
 
 
 echo $four_days_have_passed;
 echo "<br>".$now;
 
 if ($now < $four_days_have_passed)
 {
  echo "<br> booya";
 }`

Comment: Well, it's up to you to not trust me and documentation. If you think that it "works there" - use it, good luck :-)

Answer (score 0):

The case of `strtotime()` function is the most easy way to handle using the format as `yyyy-mm-dd`. This is normal format in db date. If you use this format help easy for compare two dates.

Comment: Welcome to SO. To make your answer really helpful you should add a small example.

Answer (score 0):

**In Europe, in particulary in France,**
we also use this format with the slash separator :

```
day/month/year
```

example for a french date : 26/08/2019